# How to make bookings from my app

Tags: android

I am having an android app for an e-shop. So far the user after he chooses an item, he gets a reservation number and then he can call the shop and using this number he can verify the order and he pays it there. What I want is to update my app and make the user be able to order and pay from the app- either with paypal or a cedit card? What should I use? Are there any references, any sample code,any books maybe on that? And how can I make it secure or test it? Is it possible in android or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://OpenPayments.Mobi. They offer a set of very advanced FREE services to incorporate In-App Purchases from any platform including Android, BlackBerry, Windows Phone, etc. They currently offer PayPal and Google checkout payments.

I also suggest you see this link  https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-payment-libraries